# AWS S3 Static Website Hosting with Vue.js is blank

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vue.js

### Description

I'm currently attempting to put my Vue.js project up on AWS using static web hosting on S3.

### Steps

√ I've first run `npm run build` inside my project which generated `./dist`, `./dist/index.html`, `./dist/static/*`

√ I've uploaded all `./dist/*` files to my bucket

√ I've created an S3 bucket with a public policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME_HERE/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

√ I've added `Static Website Hosting property` and set the Index-document to `index.html`

X When visiting `https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME_HERE/index.html` my app is running

### Errors:

When checking the console, the only errors I have are the following:

```
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/app.139eb30c5abb8a0cf50add8e31aed259.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/static/favicon.ico 403 (Forbidden)
```

Any leads as to what I may have missed or am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try ```"Principal": "*"``` RE https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html

Comment: Also looks like you are not using relative urls, which is why it's trying to load from the `/static` location. Either use relative urls or use the domain with the bucket name in it: https://BUCKET_NAME_HERE.s3.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your web page is attempting to load assets from the wrong location. You are seeing 403 (Forbidden) and that's because your page is accidentally specifying an S3 bucket name of 'static' which either does not exist or you do not have access to it. This URL is incorrect:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/app.xxx.css

If you intend to use path-style URLs for static assets then URLs should be of the form:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/static/css/app.xxx.css

Alternatively, you can use virtual-hosted–style URLs, of the form:

- https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/app.xxx.css

Note the inclusion of 'mybucket' in both URLs.

Comment: I see what the issue is. In this case, I'm not sure what is wrong in my html file (which is the one that makes all the requests). This is what <head> looks like:
`<link href=/static/favicon.ico rel=icon type=image/x-icon>`
`<link href=/static/css/app.139eb30c5abb8a0cf50add8e31aed259.css rel=stylesheet>`

Comment: Try a relative URI: <link href=static/css/app.xxx.css rel=stylesheet>